# Referencing specific tables (<tbody>) by ID in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a website with three tables on it and a JavaScript search compoment that allows the user to search each table. However because the JavaScript refers to the  tag and not a specific ID for each table, it means when the user searches it searches all tables. How can I write in JavaScript that it must refer to X

Here's my JavaScript:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $(".search").keyup(function () {
         var searchTerm = $(".search").val();
         var listItem = $('.results tbody').children('tr');
         var searchSplit = searchTerm.replace(/ /g, "'):containsi('")

         $.extend($.expr[':'], {
             'containsi': function (elem, i, match, array) {
                 return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || '').toLowerCase().indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
             }
         });

         $(".results tbody tr").not(":containsi('" + searchSplit + "')").each(function (e) {
             $(this).attr('visible', 'false');
         });

         $(".results tbody tr:containsi('" + searchSplit + "')").each(function (e) {
             $(this).attr('visible', 'true');
         });

         var jobCount = $('.results tbody tr[visible="true"]').length;
         $('.counter').text(jobCount + ' item');

         if (jobCount == '0') {
             $('.no-result').show();
         } else {
             $('.no-result').hide();
         }
     });
 });
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two way :

- adding an `id` on your table and working with`$("#myID")` Jquery
- work with the DOM object that make the call : `<table onclick="f(this)">`